# Why does a column becomes ambiguous when I JOIN a table?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to accomplish this : 
[image]

*with*: (Getting an error "Error Code: 1052. Column 'INV_NUMBER' in field list is ambiguous
")

```
SELECT CONCAT(CUS_FNAME, " " ,CUS_LNAME) AS 'Customer', 
INV_NUMBER AS 'inv_number',
DATE_FORMAT(invoice.INV_DATE, '%W') AS 'Day of Week' 
SUM(line.LINE_PRICE)

FROM customer

RIGHT JOIN INVOICE ON invoice.CUS_CODE = customer.CUS_CODE
JOIN LINE

WHERE CUS_FNAME LIKE 'Leona%' 
OR CUS_FNAME LIKE '%Paul%'
OR CUS_FNAME LIKE  '%Myron%' 

GROUP BY INV_NUMBER;
```

As opposed to this :

[image]

*with*:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CUS_FNAME, " " ,CUS_LNAME) AS 'Customer', 
INV_NUMBER AS 'inv_number',
DATE_FORMAT(invoice.INV_DATE, '%W') AS 'Day of Week' 

FROM customer

RIGHT JOIN INVOICE ON invoice.CUS_CODE = customer.CUS_CODE


WHERE CUS_FNAME LIKE 'Leona%' 
OR CUS_FNAME LIKE '%Paul%'
OR CUS_FNAME LIKE  '%Myron%' 

GROUP BY INV_NUMBER;
```

Here's the ERD:

[image]

*(Better Explanation?)* My second code is what I came up with while working on the question and got everything working up until I added some statements like in my first code. I am trying to add the column "Money Spent" but I keep getting an error which is:

> Error Code: 1052. Column 'INV_NUMBER' in field list is ambiguous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `INV_NUMBER` could be from `LINE` or `INVOICE`. Specify it in your select:

```
SELECT
  `INVOICE`.`INV_NUMBER` AS 'inv_number'
```

Comment: True. I am just not getting the right prices now but can take it from there. Thank you !!